# Server and Client type Subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

What is Server and Client type subscriptions in Merge Replication? How to select one of these during merge replication setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server subscriptions are for:

1. Republishing data
2. Serve as alternate synchronization partners (This has been deprecated)
3. Resolving conflicts according to a priority

If your subscription(s) do not require this behavior then a client subscription will work just fine.  This is covered in [Subscription Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188188.aspx).

The Merge subscription type can be specified on the **Subscription Type** page of the *New Subscription Wizard* or by specifying a value of **local** (client) or **global** (server) for the **@subscriber_type** parameter in [sp_addmergesubscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187717.aspx) and [sp_addmergepullsubscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189456.aspx).  This is covered in [Specify a Merge Subscription Type and Conflict Resolution Priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151214.aspx).

I hope this helps.